# Regex Custom Email Validation

Tags: javascript, html, regex, vue.js, validation

I've been trying to get my own custom email validation made in order to support things like Chinese Characters which the native email input doesn't support. I've been using regex to get this to work, I'm looking for the email validation to check if the email has at least one character before @, at least one character after @, and at least one character after the dot. So something like s@s.s should be valid. Here's a test I threw together to check if Chinese characters would be shown as valid but so far they're not, for example this one:
一个@阿育王. 巴拉特 -
Can anyone help me figure this out?
https://jsfiddle.net/qj1wzx8p/

A previous pattern I've used for the regex has been:

```
/^[^ ]+@[^ ]+\.[^ ]{2,3}$/
```

Comment: Does [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/VToJBd/1) meet your requirements?

Comment: Yes! I don't really understand the regex all that well but it seems to work lol if you can, could you go over what the regex is describing as the requirements in an answer so I can mark it as the answer for this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You change onkeydown to onchange in input tag.

And this email: 一个@阿育王. 巴拉特 you remove space after dot like: 一个@阿育王.巴拉特

And Regex pattern: /^[^ ]+@[^ ]+.[^ ]{1,}$/